# multiple app.config in c# solution

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a C# solution having multiple projects. In the solution, there is an 'App.config' file. This file is imported in 2 or 3 projects. These projects also have their own 'app.config' files in their respective folders.

Not, my doubt is that if I do

```
Configurationmanager.GetSection("section_name")
```

then from which of the config files the values will be read?

Also, is there a difference in way these two config files are interpreted. I mean App.config (with capital A) and app.config.

Thanks.

Comment: **then from which of the config files the values will be read?** Try it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is the application / project you running. If you are running from Visual Studio it will be the project you have set as the Setup Project. You can normally tell which this is as the name will be in **bold**

If you have multiple projects starting up they will all use their own app.config files.